# Optimize away unused parameterized fields

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to define a parent class for a hierarchy of "codecs" that operate on a memory "`membuf`" - some of these codecs are purely functional, but some need to have (non-local) side-effects, like setting a bit in a byte somewhere ("`flags`" below). So, I'd like to have 2 parent classes, essentially, one that has a member `flag_type*`, and one that doesn't, and I'd like to save the 8 bytes of the `flag_type*` - I tried to define a second base class, with no template parameters and no member `flag_type*` but that didn't work. Any idea?

```
template <typename flag_type =void>
class Codec
{
  public:
    Codec(flag_type* flags =nullptr)
    : _mem(graph.mem()), _flags(flags)
  {}

  protected:
    membuf& _mem;
    flag_type* _flags;
};
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about "that didn't work"? What exactly did you try and what was the error you got?

Comment: I tried to define a template<> class Codec<>, and just class Codec. Neither is accepted by the compiler in conjunction with the templated class above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do specialization, something like:

```
struct no_tag{}; // Used to specify no flag type

template <typename flag_type =void>
class Codec
{
  public:
    Codec(flag_type* flags =nullptr)
    : _mem(graph.mem()), _flags(flags)
  {}

  protected:
    membuf& _mem;
    flag_type* _flags;
};


template <>
class Codec<no_tag>
{
  public:
    Codec() : _mem(graph.mem()) {}

  protected:
    membuf& _mem;
};
```

Comment: I don't think that works. Try sizeof on both Codec<char> and Codec<>. I get 16 bytes for both on my machine. If I remove =void in the first definition, it does not compile anymore.

Comment: So the compiler is just selecting the first template in both cases, never the specialization, and I still have a class with the weight of 2 8 byte pointers. What will make the compiler consider the specialization for Codec<>?

Comment: `Codec<>` takes the general definition with the default parameter. To select the specialisation you need `Codec<no_tag `

Comment: OK, it works if using the specialization correctly with Codec<no_tag>. Then the compiler selects the specialization, which is 8 bytes only on my machine. Thanks!